# Not showing Developer Options on S7 edge or any other phone

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

Hello I have an issue with my old Samsung Galaxy S7 edge. I have rooted it and flashed another kernel(MoRoKernel v8.6.1). When I try to enable developer options by tapping 7  times Build number it pops "Developer options are already enabled" but when I go to the setting menu I cannot find it. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Probably the flag for the developer option for some reason stuck but thanks to this adb command:

```
adb shell settings put global development_settings_enabled 0
```

and tapping 7 times build number the issue solved